# How to differentiate actual mouse clicks from script generated clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tabs.It has auto play.

Take a look for example : http://jsfiddle.net/w3father/YEcZc/

How do I get click detail which suggests if it is a click from script?

Comment: Do you mean "how do I tell if an event is fired by `.click()` or by the user?"?

Answer (score 3):

What I would generally do is use two different events but the same handler:

```
$('#tabs > a').bind('click auto-click', function(ev) {
  var wasRealClick = ev.type === "click";
  // ...
});
```

Then your timer-driven code should trigger "auto-click" instead of "click".

```
function cycle() {

    // simulate click on current tab
    $("#tabs > a").eq(currTab).trigger('auto-click');
```